# TypeError while loading the pickle file using pickle.load() in python3:jupyter notebook

Tags: pickle

TypeError while loading the pickle file using pickle.load() in python3:jupyter notebook

```
with open("/home/amit/Downloads/may2_18_company_data_with_cluster.pickle","r",encoding='utf8') as f:
    c = pickle.load(f) //this line shows an error
```

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Please help me to fix this on jupyter notebook with python3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review the following link: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  this will increase the chances of getting the question answered and will help other developers who may have a similar question in the future.

Comment: It worked by using pd.read_pickle(filename) but I would like to know what is the problem in the above method and what exactly does it mean by this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `pickle.load` expects a binary type file as an argument, you need to specify this in the use of `open` by specifying `rb` for read binary instead of 'r' which reads as a string. Changing the code to:

```
with open("/home/amit/Downloads/may2_18_company_data_with_cluster.pickle","rb",encoding='utf8') as f:
    c = pickle.load(f)
```

should solve this.